# Pipes vs asynchronous channels in Racket

Tags: concurrency, racket, channel

Racket has both a notion of [pipes](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/pipeports.html?q=pipe#%28tech._pipe%29) and [channels](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/channel.html?q=channel#%28tech._channel%29).

In the case of a pipe (created with `make-pipe`), any data written to the output port, can be read from the associated input port.

Channels are similar, but with one major difference: writing something to the input blocks until the output is simultaneously read. This is particularly useful for concurrency as it can be used for inter-thread communication and synchronization.

Racket also have a notion of [asynchronous channels](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/async-channel.html?q=async-channel). These are similar to plain channels, but additionally have a buffer. If data is written to the buffer and it is not full, than the writing thread continues. The reading thread will block if the queue is empty, but otherwise it can read the latest data and continue on.

The question is, what is the difference between a pipe and an asynchronous channel? Clearly asynchronous channels were created with threads in mind, while pipes are independent of threading. But both APIs seem to serve a near identical purpose:

1. Provide a (possibly infinite) buffer where some producer can put input.
2. Provide an output for some consumer to get the data on the buffer.
3. Allow the consumer to wait until data is available.
4. Allow the producer to place input and continue execution.

The main difference between the two seems to be with the items placed in each. Pipes seem designed to mostly handle text (and bytes), and set their size accordingly. Where as channels handle items placed in the queue, rather than the size of those items themselves.

For example, a buffer size of '2' could hold a string with 2 bytes in it, while an asynchronous channel with a buffer size of '2' can hold 2 items, however large those items are.

This would lead one to think that maybe pipes are only used for text, where channels are more general. However, non-textual items can still be written to pipes, as shown with [`make-pipe-with-specials`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/port-lib.html?q=make-pipe#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fport..rkt%29._make-pipe-with-specials%29%29).

So, what is the different uses between asynchronous channels and pipes?

Answer (score 1):

Pipes are ports, and so carry bytes. Channels carry arbitrary values.

Certainly you can `write` some nontrivial value to a pipe and `read` it back on the other side. But fundamentally it's being converted into bytes, sent through the pipe, and turned back into a value on the other end. Channels skip that.

This means you can send values through channels that would not survive the trip through `write` and `read` and so can't be sent through a pipe. Unreadable values like structures that have a custom-write procedure and, well, ports!

This is my understanding. I haven't read the code. Just the documentation. I learned from the links you gave as well as the documentation for [print-unreadable](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Writing.html?q=pipe#%28def._%28%28quote._%7E23%7E25kernel%29._print-unreadable%29%29) and [The Printer](https://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/printing.html).

Comment: I don't think this is entirely correct. At least not when specials are involved:

#lang racket

(define-values (in out) (make-pipe-with-specials))
(struct foo (val))
(write-special (foo 42) out)
(foo-val (read in))

Comment: Since SO kills formatting in comments, I've pasted it here: http://pasterack.org/pastes/6313

Comment: Oh, interesting. I didn't know about specials before. I suppose I should edit my answer. How about the difference in synchronicity? Sending on a channel blocks until the value is received on the other end, doesn't it? Whereas a port may or may not have a buffer and writing may or may not return immediately depending on the fullness of the buffer or whether the write can be completed. So channels are in a sense always suitable for synchronization whereas ports may not be the best choice. Yes, there are asynchronous channels, so the lines get blurry. Maybe the biggest difference is conceptual.

Comment: "Maybe the biggest difference is conceptual" Sadly I 'think' that's the biggest difference, at least that I've been able to find. Like, it feels like ports were _designed_ to carry bites, and specials were an afterthought addon for DrRacket, while channels were designed to connect two threads together.

Comment: Actually, that may be the biggest difference, you can synchronize channels, but you can't write directly to a file, where as you can do the exact opposite with ports.  (That, plus the fact that specials feel like a half-baked addon.)